# CSS :after image not showing up - IE8

Tags: html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

EDIT: Can't believe I forgot to specify, this problem is in IE8

I have a form with a bunch of checkboxes set up like the following:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="fields" id="Anesthesiology" /><label for="Anesthesiology">Anesthesiology</label>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 16px 0 0;
  font: 13px/16px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #656565;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.checkbox + label:before {
  content:" ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.checkbox.checked + label:after {
  content:" ";
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: url(../images/checkmark.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 2px;
}
```

What this is doing is hiding the default checkbox and creating a new checkbox as :before of the label (which is showing up in ie8). When the label is clicked, a class of `.checked` is being appended to the checkbox input tag, which should then make the `:after` checkmark background image appear. I have also tried using a span inside of the label for the same effect, but nothing seems to work. The classes are being appended properly, but the :after checkmark never shows up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check you understanding of :after on the link here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: Yes, I know how to use them, the :before's and :after's are showing up in the computed styles, but when the .checked comes into play, they're nowhere to be found. If I add the :after to a non checked input it shows up as well, so I know it is not a positioning thing.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle and this seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/pWb3x/  What's different with your code?

Comment: yeah, can't believe i forgot to say this problem is in ie8

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304076(v=vs.85).aspx Try using ::after. Shot in the dark, but it might work...ie works in strange ways

Comment: I have tried that actually, still nothing :/

Comment: If you apply 'overflow: visible;' to the '.checkbox + label' does anything change?

Comment: It will not solve your problem but instead of appending a class checked to your checked checkbox, you could use the css selector :checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have <strike>a</strike> another working example <kbd>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ay2QU/1/)</kbd>.

(Tested working in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, IE10 and IE8)
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Anesthesiology_1" value="true" class="AnesthesiologyCheckbox" id="Anesthesiology_1">
<label for="Anesthesiology_1" class="AnesthesiologyLabel">Anesthesiology</label>
```

CSS:

```
.AnesthesiologyCheckbox {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;

    -moz-appearance: none;
    position:relative;
    left:-100%;
}
```

Comment: yeah, can't believe i forgot to say this problem is in ie8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Athari yeah, but it still doesn't work in IE8 so I'm trying to figure out first before updating my post

Comment: @EvanWard I've updated the post, does it work for you now in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

The class is being appended or replaced?  What happens if you change

```
.checkbox.checked + label:after {
```

To

```
.checked + label:after {
```

Comment: I have tried this, have even used an !important tag on it. Unfortunately, didn't change anything.

Comment: My next step would likely be to test it out in Chrome and use F12 to see exactly what style attributes are active at the moment on that element.  I've found that to be invaluable.